# Creating a search bar in a chrome extension that will open in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a google search bar in a chrome extension that will open the search in a new browser tab.  My manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "Search",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Search",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "search.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
   }
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="search">
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
<div style="border:0px solid black;padding:2px;width:20em;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>
<input type="text"   name="q" size="25"
 maxlength="255" value=""<textarea placeholder="Search Google"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Search" /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This html page works fine in a normal browswer but not as a chrome extension.  I think that I need to give permission to access my tabs but I am new to making chrome extensions so I am having a little bit of trouble with my rigid manifest.json markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `target="_blank"` attribute to your form, like so:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes))